# Getting pointer to element in a list

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator

I have a list full of `struct account`.

I want to return from my function a pointer of type `account*`. How do it do it?

```
account* find_account(int ID){
    for (list<account>::iterator i = accounts_database.begin; i != accounts_database.end; i++ ){
        if (i->id==ID)
            return &(*(i));
    }
    else return NULL; 
}
```

This does not work... 
Any idea what is the right way to get the `account*` from the iterator?

Comment: "This does not work" - what error do you get? I'm guess something about `const`? Hint: you use a `const_iterator`, but then return a non-`const` pointer.

Comment: changed it but still doesnt work

Comment: Please provide the actual error, and an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would probably be a good idea too.

Comment: There is no `for-else` construct in C++ like there is in Python.  Just remove the `else` keyword and it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `()` behind `begin` and `end`. Also using C++11 style, I would write the code like this, which looks a lot nicer.

```
account* find_account(int ID)
{
    for ( auto & elem : accounts_database )
        if ( elem.id == ID )
            return &elem;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <list>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


struct account
{
    int id;
    string name;
};
account* find_account(int);
account* find_account(int ID)
 {
    list<account*> accounts_database;
    account* a1,*a2;
    a1= new account();
    a2= new account();
    a1->id = 10;
    a1->name = "C++";
    a2->id = 30;
    a2->name = "Java";
    account* result_found= new account();
    accounts_database.push_back(a1);
    accounts_database.push_back(a2);
    list<account*>::const_iterator i;
    for(i = accounts_database.begin(); i != accounts_database.end(); ++i) 
    {
        if ((*i)->id==ID)
        {
            result_found = *i;
            break;
        }
        else
            result_found = NULL; 
    }
    return result_found;
}
int main( )
{
   account* a = find_account(30);
   return 0;
}
```

Above code might help you better.
Just I have written a rough code, please try to optimize as much as possible.

comments are welcome...